# How to display a certain number of characters for content that is called from a database using laravel?

Tags: laravel

How to display a certain number of characters for content that is called from a database using laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question should be more meaningful. But I think this may helps you. Use `str_limit()`

```
{{str_limit($variable_name, $limit = 30, $end = '...') }}
```

$limit can be changed as you wants

Comment: i need to return for example 100 character of a text from database to the user front page

Comment: @user10331501 so change `$limit = 100 `. That's all

Comment: Beware with the content while limiting by characters instead of words. You can cut a word and loss the meaning of the text you want to limit i.e. "`while we assembled`" to "`while we ***...`". You should try to consider this case within your test cases